# Alignment in a table using python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I want to align the items count, price and total RIGHT in a cell.
But it doesn't work with WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT

```
table.columns[0].width = Inches(14.0)
table.columns[1].width = Inches(2.0)
table.columns[2].width = Inches(2.0)
table.columns[3].width = Inches(3.0)

hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].paragraphs [0].add_run("article")
hdr_cells[1].paragraphs [0].add_run("count")
hdr_cells[2].paragraphs [0].add_run("price")
hdr_cells[3].paragraphs [0].add_run("total")

for i in range (0, len(records)):
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].paragraphs [0].add_run(records[i][0])
    row_cells[1].paragraphs [0].add_run(records[i][1])
    row_cells[2].paragraphs [0].add_run(records[i][2])
    row_cells[3].paragraphs [0].add_run(records[i][3])
```

'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, this will work as WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH will help align your content within the table

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

you can also use 'LEFT', or 'CENTER' in place of 'RIGHT' if it aligns with your needs